# How could you use PHP and a SQL database to change HTML <h> content?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, while-loop

I have a webpage that displays cars from the first car in the table to the last car with a while loop.

I have the following columns: Make, Model, Price. In my syntax I have an anchor tag around the Make rows that links to the description page of the Make you click on.

I want my `<h>` tags to change to the Model of the corresponding Make.

I've spent over an hour trying to achieve this but all I could come up with is this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT Model FROM inventory;";

$Vtitle = $conn->query($query);
$Vtitle_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Vtitle);
echo "<h1>".$Vtitle_ar['Model']."</h1>";
?>
```

This works to an extent.

Every anchor I click replaces the `<h>` tags with only the first result under the Model column in my database.

Here is my code for the the entire car inventory page

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM inventory;";
    /* Try to query the database */
    if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
      // Don't do anything if successful.
    }
    else {
      echo "Error getting cars from database:" .$conn->error()."<br>";
    }

    // Create the table headers
    echo "<table id='Grid' style='width: 80%'><tr>";
    echo "<th style='width: 50px'>Make</th>";
    echo "<th style='width: 50px'>Model</th>";
    echo "<th style='width: 50px'>Asking Price</th>";
    echo "</tr>\n";

    $class = "odd"; // keep track of whether a row was even or odd, so we can style it later

    // Loop through all the rows returned by the query, creating a table for each row
    while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<tr class=\"$class\">";
      echo "<td><a href='viewcar.php?VIN=".$result_ar['VIN']."'>".$result_ar['Make']."<a></td>";
      echo "<td>".$result_ar['Model']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$result_ar['ASKING_PRICE']."</td>";
      echo "</td></tr>\n";

      // if the last row was even, make the next one odd and vice-versa
      if ($class=="odd") {
        $class = "even";
      }
      else {
        $class = "odd";
      }
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Does anyone how I can do this?

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to use this for an actual project I'm working on for a hair salon's website

Comment: `SELECT Model FROM inventory WHERE VIN=YOUR_VALUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause to the query.

```
$vin = $_GET['VIN'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Model FROM inventory WHERE VIN = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vin);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($model);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "<h1>$model</h1>";
```

Comment: This works, I'm sure you know that. Thank you I actually understand the concept behind it too. I was thinking about using a prepared statement I just didn't know how I would do it but this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Though not a solution resolved with the use of a `where` clause as given by @Barmar whilst formatting the code I did find an error within the HTML which was not immediately obvious

The line `echo "</td></tr>\n";` has an extra `</td>` which would break the flow of the html and can have detrimental effects. Also, `// Don't do anything if successful.` makes no sense - if there are results then process the recordset otherwise show the error ;-)

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM inventory;";

    if ( $result = $conn->query( $query ) ) {
        echo "
        <table id='Grid' style='width: 80%'>
            <tr>
                <th style='width: 50px'>Make</th>
                <th style='width: 50px'>Model</th>
                <th style='width: 50px'>Asking Price</th>
            </tr>";

        $i=0;


        while( $result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
            $class = $i %2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';

            echo "
                <tr class='$class'>
                    <td><a href='viewcar.php?VIN={$result_ar['VIN']}'>{$result_ar['Make']}<a></td>
                    <td>{$result_ar['Model']}</td>
                    <td>{$result_ar['ASKING_PRICE']}</td>
                </tr>";

            $i++;
        }

        echo "</table>";

    } else {
      echo "Error getting cars from database:" .$conn->error()."<br>";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

For styling alternate table rows ( the above uses a `modulus` function to calculate odd/even ) you can do it with some simple CSS - such as

```
tr:nth-child( odd ){/* rules */}
```